# How to prevent distorted images?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have the problem that the images I add are distorted. I have created a pixel accurate background for the iPhone X at `(1125 x 2436)`, so I don't have to use `.aspectFill` and `.aspectFit` because I want a screen without black borders.

I use the following code to create the images:

```
func animateDeck() {
    let chip = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Chip")
    chip.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 400)
    chip.zPosition = 2
    chip.setScale(1)
    gameScene2.addChild(chip)
    print("test")
}
```

Is there a way to display the images in their correct size without using `.aspectFit` or `.aspectFill`?

[now (left) and how it should be (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVxyI.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have an image which is **exactly** the same size as the iPhone X, and set the position to `view.center`, you should be fine. However, even if it should fit perfect, set it to `aspectFill` or `aspectFit` just so you don't get distortion on other screen sizes.

Comment: Try also checking to see that `chip` is at your expected size - and if not, you can set it using `chip.size = CGSize(width: 1125, height: 2436)`.

Comment: I have created a new image with the size 1125 x 2436. In the middle is the 128x128 chip. The rest of the image is transparent. Unfortunately this does not work. With the other variant `gameScene2.scaleMode = .aspectFit` black bars are displayed again, which I want to prevent.

Comment: Why don’t you consider adding a `UIImage` to the view controller instead of the scene if you are not moving the background?

Comment: When I use `let image = UIImage(named: "Chip")`, I cannot use it as a node. So I can no longer use SKPhysicsBody, SKAction, etc. avail

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to have a static background, but it has a `physicsBody` so your scene has a frame which nodes cannot go through?

Comment: The background itself won't actually move. I could imagine, however, that I replaced the background image with another image in the course of the game. The content of the `animateDeck()` function (that is the chip) will move, should be clickable etc.

Comment: Can you please add an image to your question to make this clearer? Thanks

Comment: I added a picture to the question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you were saying it was a background image from your original question! My mistake... Ok, so you want to set the size of your sprite to the same **points** as your texture/image.

Comment: I'm not sure, does that mean the picture's (nodes) not distorted anymore?

Comment: It shouldn't be distorted if you do that, no. You could also try to initialise the sprite node with an `SKTexture(named: "texture")` instead, which means that you shouldn't need to change the size.

Comment: It's very hard to decide what you need, because I don't know if you have any other code changing the `chip` size or anything.

Comment: Also, what are your texture sizes (exactly)?

Comment: The size of the background is 1125 x 2436. The chip (see picture above) has a size of 128x128. But I want to add more objects with different sizes soon.

Comment: The background shouldn't affect the size of the chip.

Comment: I tried the other variant with `SKTexture`: `let chipTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Chip")`
`var chip = SKSpriteNode()` above and `chip = SKSpriteNode(texture: chipTexture)` in the function `animateDeck()`. Unfortunately the picture is also distorted

Comment: Add the image to the question or just send the link from imgur, so I can test it in my own project.

Comment: I created a GameScene like this: `gameScene2 = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1536, height: 2048))` When I create the chip, I use `gameScene2. addChild(chip)`. Maybe there's a mistake here. **EDIT:** I have already linked the picture above

Comment: The link: https://prnt.sc/le8s2n

Comment: Check out [this project I just made](https://github.com/George-J-E/TestingTextures/) to show you how to create a texture and apply it to a node. All you need is in `GameScene.swift`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I fixed the problem by using this line `gameScene2 = GameScene(size: view. bounds. size)`. (Your project gave me this idea) How can I mark your comment as the solution?

Comment: I used your answer and my comment, and I added it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this project I just made](https://github.com/George-J-E/TestingTextures/) to show you how to create a texture and apply it to a node. All you need should be in `GameScene.swift`.

Also, in your `ViewController`, make sure that your `GameScene` is initialised properly as shown in my project, or how you did it with this:

```
gameScene2 = GameScene(size: view, bounds: size)
```

Comment: I never recommend doing this, set the sks to the size of iphone x instead.  You should be designing your scene with 1 size in mind, programming like this is only going to hurt you in the long run.